# Java: Download always stalls

Tags: java, windows-7, tcp, download

Some days ago I run into a severe problem that gives me a headache:

All Java based tools (Eclipse, Maven, Android SDK loader...) have problems downloading certain files: the download just stops at random.

I already described my problem at [Superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/410883/downloads-stops-tcp-window-full) but nobody was able to help me with my problem. Therefore started to perform some tests myself and ended up with the sample code at the end of this question.

The interesting part is that the buffer size has an small influence on the problem. If I reduce the buffer size to 1024 the download completes in most cases.

Does this code only make problems on my Windows system?

To make it clear: I don't want to develop a download program with Java - therefore fixing the sample code does not help me - the code is only for demonstrating the problem.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://mirror.netcologne.de/maven2/com/google/android/android/2.3.3/android-2.3.3.jar");

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[10485760]; // 10MiB
        long read = 0;
        while (true) {
            int bytes = in.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
            if (bytes < 0)
                break;
            read += bytes;
            System.out.println("Bytes read: " + read);
        }
        conn.disconnect();
        System.out.println("Finished");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: How does it stop?  Does it throw an exception?  Does it hang?  Does it timeout?  Does it read so many bytes but not the whole file?

Comment: @Marlin: The data flow is just going to zero, no Exception and no timeout. Sometimes it stops after loading ~ 1.4 MiB sometimes at 3.2 MiB (or other values).

Comment: How long did you wait while the data flow stopped?  What is the round trip latency when the data flow stops?  You can determine the latency with ping.

Comment: @Marlin: I waited minutes. Please see the linked supersuer question for understanding that network latency is not a problem in this case.

Comment: Read the SuperUser post,

Comment: Read the SuperUser post, and still want to know the latency at the time the download hangs.  It's not that I think you have a latency problem, but a gateway (router, switch, et al.) could get saturated and send a quench, which might make the latency different when the hang occurs.  From the TCP window full message, and from your experiment with different buffer lengths, it may have to do with how fast the data is being read from the TCP layer vs how fast it is coming over the network, and the TCP buffer (which is a buffer in the TCP layer).

Comment: @Marlin: At the moment the stall occurs the latency raises from 30 to 60 msec in about 2 seconds. Afterwards it returns immediately back to 30msec.

Comment: I'm not exactly an expert, but what it looks like is that your application has stopped reading.  If it fell behind, there might be a TCP window full message, but if the application resumed reading, then the data transfer would resume.  So what you are seeing is what you would expect if the app stops reading, and TCP figures out that it has no room in the TCP buffer/(window) so it should stop sending data.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. If I observe the TCP stream via Wireshark and count the downloaded bytes minus HTTP header I get a value that is 66600 higher that the bytes counter shown by my sample code. Therefore this seems to be a bug of Java JRE or the Windows TCP stack.

Comment: The higher number of bytes sent over the wire than "read" could be because of a TCP buffer.  So, if you counter says 100,000, and Wireshark indicates 166,600, your application has read 100,000, and there are 66,600 unread but transmitted bytes sitting in the TCP buffer.  This is the window which filled up to send the TCP Window full.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing is caused by Java 7 - in detail that to gives IPv6 a higher priority than IPv4.

This problem affects all Java based software but only occurs on some computers (may depend on the used Internet connection and/or local network components like switches, router...)

You can change it back to IPv4 as it was used in Java 6 by setting the system property `java.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`

Setting this property is different for each application. For Eclipse you have to set it in the eclipse.ini.

For Andoird SDK manager you have to edit the file `tools\android.bat` and add the parameter `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` to the Java call near the end of the file.